# Trying to trivialize $T_pS^1$ "trivially"

Tags: vector-spaces, differential-topology, tangent-bundle

I would like to trivialize explicitely and in the simplest possible way the tangent bundle $T_pS^1$ finding a diffeomorphism $T_pS^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ whose restriction to each point $p$ of $S^1$ is a vector space isomorphism between the tangent space at $p$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

In order to do so I introduce an atlas on $S_1$ made of the two following maps:
$$\phi_1(p) = \theta_1, 0<\theta_1<2\pi $$ where $\theta_1$ is the angle between the positive horizontal semiaxis and the radius at $p$ (i.e. the "phase" of $p$ if seen as a complex number), and
$$\phi_2(p) = \theta_2, -\pi<\theta_2<\pi $$
with the smooth transition function $\theta_2 = \pi - \theta_1$. The map $\phi_1$ covers the open set $S_1 - (0,1)$ while $\phi_2$ covers the open set $S_1 - (-1,0)$.
I understand we can give $T_pS^1$ the differential structure induced by the maps $(\phi_1(p),\phi_{1*}(v))$ and $(\phi_2(p),\phi_{2*}(v))$ where $v$ is a tangent vector at $p$ and $\phi_{1*}$ and $\phi_{2*}$ are the differentials of $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ respectively. This means that if I have a curve $\theta_1=k_1t+\theta_1(p)$ its velocity at $\theta_1(p)$ (a tangent vector at $p$) can be identified as $k_1$, hence either $k_1=\phi_{1*}(v)$ or $k_2=\phi_{2*}(v)$ be chosen as a coordinate of the single dimensional tangent space at $p$ where $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ are defined respectively.

For each $(p,v) \in TS^1$ I introduce the following function $D: TS^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$

$$D(p,v)=(p,\phi_{1*}(v)), \text{ if } p \neq (0,1)$$
$$D(p,v)=(p,-\phi_{2*}(v)), \text{ if } p = (0,1)$$

I believe that $D$ is the diffeomorphism I am searching for, because it smooth at each $p$ and, in particular, also at $(0,1)$, because in an open set of $S^1$ around $(0,1)$ $D$ is identical to $(p,-\phi_{2*}(v))$.

I am saying this because given to $T_pS^1$ the differential structure induced by the maps $(\phi_1(p),\phi_{1*}(v))$ and $(\phi_2(p),\phi_{2*}(v))$, $D$ is by definition a diffeomorphism as it is continous and its pullbacks to the coordinate functions are the diffeomorphisms $(\theta_1,k_1) \rightarrow (\theta_1,k_1)$ and $(\theta_2,k_2) \rightarrow (\theta_2,-k_2)$.

Does my reasoning make sense?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: if you know that for $p = (x, y)\in  S^1,\ T_pS^1$ is spanned by $(−y, x) $, then you can play around a bit to find an explicit diffeomorphism that makes the required diagram commute.

Comment: @Matematleta thanks. First of all I have edited my post to write correctly $T_pS^1$ :) Could you please tell me the diffeomorphism you had in mind?

Comment: Also, do I really need to represent the tangent vectors of $S^1$ as vectors in the plane?
Anyways, if I took your suggestion right, I believe I can represent each vector as $t(-sin(\theta_1), cos(\theta_1)$ or $t(sin(\theta_2),-cos(\theta_2))$. This allows me to put in place a correspondence between $T_pS^1$ and the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ... but then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your idea in the comments, we have that at each point $(x,y)\in S^1$ a basis vector for $T_{(x,y)}S^1$ is given by $-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ so we can take $\varphi: ((x,y),t)\mapsto ((x, y), t\left(-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right))$ which we may as well write $((x,y),t)\mapsto ((x, y), t(-y,x)).$ This is clearly a diffeomorphism that satisfies $\pi\circ \varphi=p$, where $\pi$ and $p$ are the projections from $TS^1$ and $S^1\times \mathbb R.$

Comment: thanks. I believe that in my edited post I've found out a similar answer (in essence, the diffeomorphism is the same only I tried to describe it via the maps I introduced, while you visualize each tangent vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$). Do you think my approach makes sense as well?

Comment: The way I see this is noting that $TS^1=\{((x,y),v) \in \mathbb{R^2} \times \mathbb{R^2}\mid f(x,y)=0 \text{ and } df_{(x,y)}(v)=0\}$ for $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1.$ This gives directly a non-vanishing global section $S^1\to TS^1:(x,y) \mapsto ((x,y),(-y,x)).$ So I know what map I want $before$ doing the calculation. I guess you are finding a parametrization for a global non-zero section of $S^1$, to prove that the tangent bundle is trivial. But I am not able to follow your proof all the way: for example, you have $p=(0,0)$ at one point. But $(0,0)\notin S^1.$

Comment: ouch! you are right. thanks. I have edited my post and amended to $(0,0)$ to $(0,1). would you be so kind to check if now works?

Comment: I believe that in your proof we can use the vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ like $a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ because you defined $S^1$ as a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (so there is an injection between one element of $T_pS^1$ and one element of $T_p\mathbb{R}^2$) correct? In my attempt I have not used this information nor the concept of non-vanishing global sections ... simply because I still haven't studied properly them yet :)

Comment: Yes, define $\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t);\ \gamma(t_0)=p\ $. Then, you get a tangent vector $\gamma'(t_0)$. Now then $\gamma'(t_0)=a\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$ so if we apply the projection $r:(x,y)\mapsto x$, we get $\gamma'(t_0)r=\frac{d(r\circ \gamma)}{dt}|_{t=t_0}=\frac{d(\cos t)}{dt}|_{t=t_0}=a\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=a\Rightarrow -\sin t_0=a$ and similarly, $b=\cos t_0.$